# Polar coordinates unit vectors proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Prove that the unit vectors in polar coordinates are related to those in rectangular coordinates by
\begin{align*}
\hat{r}&=\hat{x}\cos\phi+\hat{y}\sin\phi\\
\hat{\phi}&=-\hat{x}\sin\phi+\hat{y}\cos\phi.
\end{align*}
What are $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ in terms of $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\phi}$?

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $\sin \phi$ and the second equation by $\cos\phi$. Add them up.

Comment: So I ended up with $rsin \phi +\phi cos\phi=y$ and $rcos \phi - \phi sin \phi =x, $ but I fail to see how this proves the relation.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see the relation:

$\vec r=x\hat x+y\hat y$

$\hat r=\dfrac{\partial\vec r}{\partial r}/\left|\dfrac{\partial\vec r}{\partial r}\right|=\cos\phi\hat x+\sin\phi\hat y$$

$\hat\phi=\dfrac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\phi}/\left|\dfrac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\phi}\right|=(-r\sin\phi\hat x+r\cos\phi\hat y)/r=-\sin\phi\hat x+\cos\phi\hat y$

Answer (score 0):

$\hat{r}=\hat{x}\cos\phi+\hat{y}\sin\phi$ is a direct consequence of the unit circle definition of sine and cosine.

As $\hat{\phi}$ is the unit vector formed by rotating $\hat{r}$ through $90^\circ$,

\begin{align*}
\hat{\phi}&=\hat{x}\cos(90^\circ+\phi)+\hat{y}\sin(90^\circ+\phi)\\
&=-\hat{x}\sin\phi+\hat{y}\cos\phi.
\end{align*}